# Error using HSQL - 2.2

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

I am getting the following error when used with HSQL-2.2.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hsqldb.DatabaseURL.parseURL(Ljava/lang/String;ZZ)Lorg/hsqldb/persist/HsqlProperties;
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2009)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1292)
...
```

This is working fine, when used with HSQL-1.8.
Can some one please help me in resolving the issue. Should I change some configuration when using 2.2 version.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this external link](http://hsqldb.10974.n7.nabble.com/NoSuchMethodError-org-hsqldb-DatabaseURL-parseURL-Ljava-lang-String-ZZ-Lorg-hsqldb-persist-HsqlPrope-td3175.html): verify your classpath, make sure that you have *only one* version of hsqldb on your (execution) classpath.

Comment: the link is broken :(